# How can I find out which service is keeping Vista from restarting?

Tags: windows-vista, shutdown, services

Running Vista on my Toshiba laptop for several years now. Recently, I noticed it will not restart - I have to power cycle it. I have enabled Verbose Status messages, so I know it's stuck at "Stopping services". Is there a way to figure out which service is not stopping? I'm hoping for some kind of log like the bootlog.

I've tried looking through the event viewer - no luck there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I had to do this the old-fashioned way, uninstall recent applications, re-boot and see if Vista still hangs during shutdown. Sure would have been nice to have a shutdown log, just like the boot log, to help the debug this!

I did find the culprit - Juniper Networks Network Connect 6.2.0 (otherwise a very fine product!) is not compatible with Vista Ultimate SP2 / IE8. Oh well - maybe Windows 7 someday?

Comment: Good to know you found it and actually this solution works for quite a lot of problems (especially related to compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

You might find information buried in your Event Viewer.

(right-click Computer, select Manage, expand Event Viewer)

Comment: This link tells you the type of event you are looking for:

http://forums.windrivers.com/archive/index.php/t-55927.html

Comment: No luck with the event viewer. It just shows normal operation

Answer (score 1):

I think that once again [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can come to the rescue.  You may have to make it replace the windows Task Manager (**Options->Replace Task Manager**) in order to open it during the shutdown process, but it may be of help.

You may also want to try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  You may have to use **File->Run...** from Process Explorer or **New Task...* from Task Manager to launch it, but it should tell you what kind of activity is taking place on your system.

Comment: +1 for what sounds like a great idea. Too bad it does not work - by the time I need to look at the shutdown process, it's too late. I do love Process Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill process one by one until  it's can restart. 
In some case I have this problem with corrupted graphics drivers.